Angular: Service inside @Input function is undefined when the function is called from outside
I have a function:
@Input getErrorFields(): Array<any> {
 this.sharedService.getErrors().then((value => {value ? this.errorFields.push(...value) : null})
 return this.errorFields;
}

My angular project is packed into a js file and integrated into a webpage. When getErrorFields is called from JavaScript code within the webpage, sharedService is undefined.
I have tried debugging to check if sharedService is initialized before the function in my component is called, and it is. Also, if getErrorFields() is called at the beginning of ngOnInit, it returns the correct value.
I have also tried binding the function due to context, but I got the same error.

This is probably a scope issue, check what this is.
But I would advise against this pattern, this is pretty much spegetti code.

Can you provide more information about your component. The use of Input decorator is not correct. You define it to pass values from parent into the child component.

@billybob412 please replicate the issue in a stackblitz and update on the question!
